# How to select key id in a struct, by a matching string variable

Tags: go

I'm interesting in to update value in to struct, but I notice lots of repeated code. Is it possible to pass Key ID in to `func(keyid string)` to use input as a selector to modify the struct? I know reflect package exists, but it's simple to return value of key field, but I can't figure out how to use it as selector of key id.

My repeated code pattern:

```
func (j *items) updatePath(n string, v string) []JSON {
    cur := j.find(n)
    if cur != -1 {
        j.items[cur].Path = v
        return j.items
    }
    return j.items
}

func (j *items) updateArgs(n string, v []string) []JSON {
    cur := j.find(n)
    if cur != -1 {
        j.items[cur].Args = v
        return j.items
    }
    return j.items
}

func (j *items) updateTimes(n string) []JSON {
    cur := j.find(n)
    if cur != -1 {
        j.items[cur].TimesRun++
        return j.items
    }
    return j.items
}
```

Reflect:

```
func (j *items) returnField(s string) string {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(j.items[0])
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(s)
    return f.String() //i can't use f as `j.items[0].f` selector.
}
```

Comment: It is only possible with reflection, or repeating code. Repeating code is generally the preferred approach, as it's much faster, and easier to read.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks, but is it okay to tripple the code basicly for a one line of code? j.items[cur].[f] will be not much complicated.

Comment: Of course it's okay. It's your code. Do what you want. You can use reflection, if you really want to, but why bother? It's slower, and it makes your code harder to read. Go's philosophy is to make your code as easy to read as possible, even if that means you write a few more lines of code. Most people spend 10x more time reading code than writing it, so I think this is an appropriate bias.

Comment: You can reduce the code by using this pattern: `func (j *items) updatePath(n string, v string) []JSON { if cur := j.find(n); cur != -1 { j.items[cur].Path = v }; return j.items }` (formatted for comment, gofmt it to remove ; and insert line breaks).  There does not appear to be a reason to return the slice, so simplify more by removing the return value.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
func (j *items) updateField(s string, vl string) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(&j.items[0])
    (val.Elem()).FieldByName(s).SetString(vl)
}
```

1. It's not slower
2. It's not harder to understand

Also i'm find out that it's also possible to do with a Map(), but it will took a lot more effort.